# Apply semantic to custom git flows

Tags: semantic-release

I've found [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) and it looks very useful. But I'm wondering how to customize it to fit our workflow:

- no dev branch, just a master and feature/fix/chore branches.
- latest release (github with relevant git tag) correspond to version pushed to production.
- Draft release correspond to version pushed to staging.

This is a private industry project, so we cannot go completely lean and must respect internal design guidelines including batching PRs on staging before releasing on production.

I can add a dev branch, and push staging from dev, then production from master after merging dev to master.
But I'd like my github draft release to be updated as soon as a pull request is merged back into dev (draft release that would become the latest release once dev is merged into master).

Is that somehow possible ? I recently installed the semantic pull request github app, and started using conventional commit conventions, but I'm unclear about how to use [release-notes-generator](https://github.com/semantic-release/release-notes-generator) on its own, or whether it handles the github draft release mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I'm wondering how to customize it to fit our workflow: * no dev branch, just a master and feature/fix/chore branches. * latest release (github with relevant git tag) correspond to version pushed to production. * Draft release correspond to version pushed to staging.

It only analyze the commit on the branch that you configure (by default `master`). It doesn't matter how the commit get there, you can merge them in any branch you want before they reach `master`. When they get to `master` and semantic-release run it will analyze the commits on `master` and make a release if necessary.

semantic-release doesn't support draft/pre-release yet (See https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/563).

> I recently installed the semantic pull request github app

What you are referring to? There is no semantic-release GitHub app at that point, even though it's planned to have one at some point (https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/585).

> but I'm unclear about how to use release-notes-generator on its own, or whether it handles the github draft release mode

`release-notes-generator` is responsible for generating the release note and doesn't interact with GitHub. The [@semantic-release/github](https://github.com/semantic-release/github) is responsible for creating the release on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the draft/pre-release support is a blocker, but I'll be following news on the related issue closely :)